# $W^{s_1 , 2} (\Bbb R^n ) \hookrightarrow W^{s_2,4}(\Bbb R^n )$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

How can I prove that $W^{s_1 , 2} (\Bbb R^n ) \hookrightarrow W^{s_2,4}(\Bbb R^n )$ if $s_1 > s_2 + n/4$ ? $W^{s,p}$ denotes a general Sobolev space for $s =0,1,2,\cdots$. The hook means a continuous embedding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem.** If the domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has the cone property, the following embeddings are continuous:
$$
W^{j+m,p}(\Omega) \subset W^{j,q}(\Omega) \quad \text{provided that $p \leq q \leq \frac{np}{n-mp}$}.
$$

If you choose $p=2$ and $q=4$, the condition reads $2 \leq 4 \leq \frac{2n}{n-2m}$, which is satisfied when $n \geq 2m$ and $m \geq \frac{n}{4}$.

Bibliography: Proposition 1 in [these notes](http://www2.icmc.usp.br/~andcarva/sobolew.pdf).